# Collection get items return null

Tags: magento2, product-collection

I tried to get all products sku, that started at `$params['sku']`
My controller:

```
<?php

namespace Aty\TestTask\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class GetProductAjax extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    private $product;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    ) {
        $this->product = $product;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

        if (!empty($params['sku'])) {
            $collection = $this->product->getCollection();
            $skus = $collection->addFieldToFilter('sku', array(
                'like' => $params['sku'].' %'
                ))
                ->getItems();
            return $skus;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it return null. Where is my fault?

Comment: First you have a space in your `like` query, what you are searching by is `sku like "abcd %"` so if you do not have sku with a space then nothing will be found. Second, you can inspect actual query that was executed by doing `$query = $collection->load()->getSelect()->__toString();`, this is very helpful during development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use below code-

```
protected $_productCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
) {
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory; 
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

    if (!empty($params['sku'])) {
        $collection =  $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection = $collection->addFieldToFilter('sku', array(
            'like' => $params['sku'].' %'
            ));
        // if you want skus only
        $skus = array();
        foreach($collection as $product)
        {
          $skus[] = $product->getSku(); 
        }
        return $skus;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It's ok. but it get a product. May be u know how. I can get just array of sku?Can u explain, why I need to create it, pls?

Comment: @Pasha, please check my updated answer please.

Comment: Ty, so mush. May be u can recommend some article, that explain about collection, and why I must create productCollection. And where I can know more about collection method like a addFieldToFilter.

Comment: to know how to use addFieldToFilter function  you can check this [link](https://www.amanweb.in/add-multiple-field-filter-addfieldtofilter-and-multiple-attribute-filter-addattributetoselect-in-magento/)